# Gradle could not resolve dependency with multiple versions declared pom.xml

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to build a project with
`compile 'org.odlabs.wiquery:wiquery-core:1.5.6'`.

Which depends on `jackson-mapper-asl`.
This dependency is declared in `org.odlabs.wiquery:wiquery-core` parent `pom.xml`. And version is declared like this:
`<jackson.version>[1.8,1.8.6],[1.9,1.9.7]</jackson.version>`

Because of that I receive errors:

```
:ui-components:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ui-components:compile'.
> Could not resolve org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:[1.8,1.8.6],[1.9,1.9.7].
  Required by:
      com.app:ui-components:1.5.8 > org.odlabs.wiquery:wiquery-core:1.5.6
   > Illegal character in path at index 70: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/[1.8,1.8.6],[1.9,1.9.7]/jackson-mapper-asl-[1.8,1.8.6],[1.9,1.9.7].pom
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you verified that this is a version notation supported by Maven? I'm afraid the only workaround might be to edit the POM in your inhouse Maven repository (not a big deal usually).

Comment: Yes, this notation works with maven. It compiles and builds in parallel (currently migrating from maven to gradle).

Comment: Please submit an issue ("problem") over at `http://forums.gradle.org`. In the meantime, if the "illegal character" is indeed about the version notation, editing the POM is likely your best chance.

Comment: What would be the best approach if there is no inhouse repo? If I would like to build project just after checking out from git repo?

Comment: You could try to bring in just the `wiquery-core` Jar (`compile 'org.odlabs.wiquery:wiquery-core:1.5.6@jar'`) and specify its transitive dependencies yourself. Given that the problem is in `wiquery-core`'s parent POM, I'm not sure if it will work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Peter Niedwerwieser suggestion just to add jar dependency. Also added transient dependencies it requires.